# Dialog Framework in PrimeFaces 4.0 not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, dialog

am trying to implement "Basic Dialog framework" but no use in implementing...
it's not showing any error in console...

xhtml page ---> program.xhtml

```
 <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/pages/BaseTemplate.xhtml">
 <ui:define name="body">
 <h:form id="form">
     <p:commandButton value="ABCD" actionListener="#{pc_Program.goToCurrentStage}"/>
 </h:form>
 </ui:define>
 </ui:composition>
```

managed bean --> Program.java

```
 @ManagedBean(name = "pc_Program")
 @SessionScoped
 public class Program{

      public void goToCurrentStage(){
     Map<String,Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
        options.put("modal", true);  
        options.put("draggable", false);  
        options.put("resizable", false);  
        options.put("contentHeight", 320);  
     RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("intimationDepositHome", options, null);
      }
 }
```

i need to open a dialog of intimationDeposit.xhtml when i click on commandbutton in program.xhtml

```
 <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/pages/BaseTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="body">
    <h:form id="form">
 <p:dataTable id="serDetails" var="bean" value="#{pc_intimationDeposit.pendingReps}" >
   <p:column headerText="Unique Id" style="width: 15px">                                        
   <h:outputText value="#{bean.uniqueId}" styleClass="box text"/>           
   </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
 </ui:define>
 </ui:composition>
```

managed bean ---> IntimationDeposit.java

```
 @ManagedBean(name = "pc_intimationDeposit")
 @SessionScoped
 public class IntimationDeposit{
 public List<PendingRep> pendingReps = new ArrayList<PendingRep>();
 //setter/getters and some logic to get PendingRep List
 }
```

in my faces-config.xml i have added...

```
 <application>
    <action-listener>org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener</action-listener>
    <navigation-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler</navigation-handler>
    <view-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
```

navigation case

---

```
 <navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>intimationDepositHome</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/pages/intimationDeposit.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

but no dialog box opened... and didn't get any error message...

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript Errors in your browser web console?

Comment: Check by including jquery-plugins.js.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible that you need to use an annotation. I have the same problema and I resolve it using annotation @postconstruct in init method and after do the //setter/getters and some logic to get PendingRep List that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same development like your code. It is work for me. But, there is no critical problem in your code, I think.

Just one mistake in your code.

```
there is no end tag `</h:form>` at `intimationDeposit.xhtml` page.
```

if so, dialog box will not open. But you will get the error like :

```
 element type "h:form" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</h:form>"
```